# Using a function call with the argument cin.get() or .getline()

Tags: c++, string, console

Is it possible to do a function call with an argument of a string using cin.get() or cin.getline()?

If not, how could i get user input from the console using a function call like this?

```
void setString(string str);
string stringText;    

void setString(string str) {
    stringText = str;
}

int main() {
    setString(cin.getline());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `free` function called getline that takes an input stream and a string as parameter, the second being an `out` parameter. It returns the stream object that was passed in, not the string.

You could however write your own function that returns a string

```
std::string getConsoleLine()
{
      std::string str;
      std::getline( std::cin, str );
      return str;
}
```

Note that, just like any other input stream, `cin` can be in a failed state from a period read. You could make your function clear any flags and ignore anything left in it first.

```
std::string getConsoleLine()
{
     // as a precaution add this lines
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() );

    std::string str;
    std::getline( std::cin, str );
    return str;
}
```

Then you could pass it to your function.

```
setString( getConsoleLine() );
```

Comment: I did not think of that, thank you! This could help me on all my future projects.

Answer (score 1):

[`cin.getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) does not return `std::string` so you cannot pass it directly as a parameter to a function.

You need to store the input in a variable

```
std::string str;
cin >> str;
```

Then pass that variable to the function:

```
setString(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. Very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string stringText;    

    // puts the input you type into stringText
    std::getline(std::cin, stringText);

    // Now do what you like with stringText
    std::cout << "You typed: " << stringText << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```